# Blender 2.79: bevel only one edge

Tags: bevel

I am trying to bevel only selected edge of the mesh. I've read blender's manual and other questions but can't achieve my goal[image]

I would accept as a valid answer completely beveling (edges and vertices) top outside perimeter.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's years since I've seen 2.79, but instead of using a Bevel modifier, can't you just select all the edges you want to bevel and use Ctrl-B? This is the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html?highlight=bevel#usage) section on using the bevel tool. You should apply the Scale to your object in Object mode and probably clear the [Sharp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?highlight=mark%20sharp#mark-sharp-and-clear-sharp) (blue) setting from those edges first.

Comment: so what difficulty do you meet, maybe share your file? Also as John says, sometimes beveling manually is simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bevel modifier has a parameter "Limit Method", you can either

• Assign your top outside perimeter vertices to a new Vertex Group, then if you set the "Limit Method" to the last option "Group" it lets you select your vertex group.

• Assign a Bevel Weight to your top outside perimeter edges, then set the "Limit Method" to the third option "Weight"

[image: Mean Bevel Weight]